# ASUS x551ma wont boot from DVD-ROM, when chosen in BIOS

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, dvd, acronis-diskdirector

I have gone through stages of ensuring that FAST START option in WIN-8 was disbled, to restarting and going into BIOS via F2, then choosing all fast boot options were disabled, then to BOOT ORDER. SAVED F10.... At reboot, it heads directly to onboard WIN-8 instead of Acronis Director suite 11. I reset the BIOS to use DVD-RAM as 1st. boot priority, and on restart, it DID use the DVD-ROM, BUT Acronis says there are NO HDD's in my Laptop then... so I reset it to HDD0, and the HD is again working... WHY? - How do I boot to DVD and format my HDD then, if it doesn't recognise my HDD? (et vice-versa)...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to boot order, you might need to change UEFI settings in BIOS (UEFI) setup, such as turning off security and allowing legacy mode. See directions specific to your computer, which is not mentioned. Here's Dell's directions, for example: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN142679/EN

It is also possible that some PC's can boot only from USB flash drives, rather than DVD.